# How does a hashmap work if all its keys have the same value?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

If I have a hashmap say `HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();` If I have all the values e.g 1 up to 100 all storing the same object. In memory, will this be 100 instances of that object or 100 pointers to one object.

Why?
Well if you have a map with `HashMap<String, Integer>` (notice the swap in generics) and the string is a word and the integer is the number of occurrences if I need to pick a word at random *however* such that it is proportional to the number of its occurences then a quick way would be just to fill an arraylist with the word "cat" 100 times and the rest accordingly (to "convert" the hashmap into an arraylist) and that way when a random number is picked using list.get(i) then its proportional to its occurences.

So this will take as n words * m occurences which means a huge list. So how efficient would it be to use a HashMap instead.

If indeed there will be pointers from the key to the value (when they repeat) then surely the map is a better approach.

Comment: That depends on whether you do  `.put(1, new String("foo")); .put(2, new String("foo")) ... `.put(100, new String("foo"))` - That will allocate 100 strings. `String foo = "foo"; .put(1, foo); .put(2, foo ... `.put(100, foo) ` will allocate 1 string. But both will allocate 100 internal entries in the map that holds the key/value pair of references. (And possibly it will also allocate  100 objects for the keys, though integers from 1-100 would be internalized)

Comment: An ArrayList is just a list of pointers, but that doesn't mean it's free. Each pointer takes up memory.

Comment: I assume new String("foo") would have the same effect as just "foo"? in terms of creating 100 objects

Comment: I think you do not understand the concept of an object reference value in java

Comment: I don't really get the point of the question but i can answer the question in the title: a Hashmap stores pointers to the object you put in there.

Comment: @Mark Not at all. `new String("foo")` explicitly (and unnecessarily) creates a distinct object.

Comment: ok so therefore it depends if doing "new" or just placing it there. ^ thats all i wanted to know. Thank you. That shouldve been an answer....

Comment: This problem is called "Fitness proportionate selection" you can find more information (and sample code) on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection)

Comment: The word pointer should be avoid when java in order to keep minds clear for C developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the two options you are considering are either :

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
words.add("cat");
words.add("cat");
...
words.add("cat");
```

vs.

```
Map<Integer,String> words = new HashMap<>();
words.put(0,"cat");
words.put(1,"cat");
...
words.put(99,"cat");
```

Both the `List` and the `Map` would contain multiple reference to the same String object ("cat"). The `Map` would require more memory, though, since it also has to store the keys.

In addition, you have no easy way of obtaining the `i`'th `String` value of the `Map` for a given random `i`, since `HashMap` has no order.

Therefore your `List` solution is preferable to your suggested `Map<Integer,String>` alternative.

That said, you could build a more efficient `TreeMap` that would allow you to get a random `String` depending on its number of occurrences.

One way I can think of :

```
TreeMap<Integer,String> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(0,"cat");
map.put(100,"dog");
```

This `TreeMap` represents 100 occurrences of "cat" and 20 occurrences of "dog". Now, if you draw a random number from 0 to 119, you can easily check whether it lands in the range of "cat" or "dog".

For example, if you draw the number 105, you obtain the corresponding `String` with :

```
String randomStr = map.ceilingEntry(105).getValue();
```

All that remains is to convert the `HashMap<String, Integer>` containing the number of occurrences to the corresponding `TreeMap<Integer, String>` :

```
HashMap<String, Integer> occurrences = ...
TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
int count = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : occurrences.entrySet()) {
    map.put (count, entry.getKey());
    count += entry.getValue();
}
```

Note that I'm using `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap` in order to be able to efficiently obtain the entry having the least key greater than or equal to the given key (without having to iterate over all the entries). This is only possible in `NavigableMap`s.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `map.put (entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());` instead? Also is the for loop order O(1) then in this case or O(n)?

Comment: @Mark The for loop is O(n) where n is the number of unique Strings. However, you only run that loop once to initialize the TreeMap. It takes less time than it takes to initialize the occurrences Map. And no, `map.put (entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());` would be wrong. What happens when two Strings have the same number of occurrences? The idea is that the first String in the occurrences Map corresponds with indices from 0 to its number of occurrences - 1, the second String corresponds with indices from count to count + its number of occurrences - 1, and so on.

Comment: Sorry I meant entry.getKey() and entry.getValue() what's their complexity?

Comment: @Mark Both are O(1)

Comment: Also why 20 dogs?

Comment: @Mark Actually, the last entry added to that Map (i.e. the entry with the highest key) represents an unbound range. This means that for any x>99, `map.ceilingEntry(x).getValue()` will return "dog" in my example. It's the responsibility of the caller not to pass too large values of x (i.e. values larger than 119 in my example). As an alternative, you can add a `map.put (count, "error");` after the loop, which will cause `map.ceilingEntry(x).getValue()` to return "error" instead of "dog" if x>119.

Answer (score 2):

After looking in the Map implemetation, Map#put() uses the static class `Node<K,V>` which is handling references

```
    static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final int hash;
    final K key;
    V value;
    Node<K,V> next;

    Node(int hash, K key, V value, Node<K,V> next) {
        this.hash = hash;
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
```

example:

```
    final Map<Integer, Point> map = new HashMap<>();

    final Point xPoint = new Point(0, 0);
    map.put(1, xPoint);
    map.put(2, xPoint);
    map.put(3, xPoint);
    System.out.println(map);
    // modify the point
    System.out.println(xPoint);
    xPoint.setX(555);
    System.out.println(xPoint);
    System.out.println(map);
```

and I gave a try defininf a custom MAp Integer, Point, (custom point)

```
    Map<Integer, Point> map = new HashMap<>();

    Point xPoint = new Point(0, 0);
    map.put(1, xPoint);
    map.put(2, xPoint);
    map.put(3, xPoint);
    System.out.println(map);
    // modify the point
    System.out.println(xPoint);
    xPoint.setX(555);
    System.out.println(xPoint);
    System.out.println(map);
```

as you can see, modifing the point will affect the hole map, since all nodes.V are pointing to the same ref.

Comment: I think you misread the question. OP was talking about different keys having identical value, not other way around.

Comment: ^ thats correct. I think you have misunderstood. I'm saying if i have map.put(1, object); and map.put(2, object); then in memory are there 2 objects? OR are there pointers from 1 and 2 to one object in memory.

Comment: Now, I got the real question :)